# Autofill until last row, countif, ready macro adjustment

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask for the help with one simple macro. It does the job for my team mates to compare the data and apply countif function and bring the proper data. However, macro has the autofill set up to D108. I would like to change it slightly to autofill it until last populated row. Could anyone help me to amend it to work as it should?

```
Sub Countif_function()

Sheets("Account Campaign Member").Select
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "How Many Contacts do we have?"
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF('Campaign Member'!C[-2],RC[-1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D108")
Range("D2:D108").Select
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:D").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Comparison").Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this update

```
Sub Countif_function()

Sheets("Account Campaign Member").Range("D1")= "How Many Contacts do we have?"
with Sheets("Account Campaign Member").Range("D2:D" & .cells(rows.count,3).end(xlup).row)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF('Campaign Member'!C[-2],RC[-1])"
    .value=.value
end With

Sheets("Account Campaign Member").Columns("B:D").copy Sheets("Comparison").Range("A1")
Sheets("Comparison").Columns("A:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("Comparison").Columns("B:B").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @nutsch, This code brings me the error in it's 4 line. The problem is with (.rows.count,3). When I delete the dot, then it runs but the same like mine - not to the end. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the leading period on .rows

Answer (score 0):

use this code
`LastRow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("D2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Range("D2"), Range("D" & LastRow))`
instead of

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D108")
```

Comment: Hi @alpha bravo, changing this code brings one problem. It does the countif for any possible cells (that is something like 100k which really slows it down. How should I amend it to populate it only to the populated cells?

Comment: @mgunia, I changed my code above, I hope I got the meaning of "populated cells" right as in column "A" cells are populated already!